# How to lookup a JSF bean from a Spring bean

Tags: spring, jsf

I am having a JSF application and I am using Spring for bean management. I registered all JSF beans as Spring beans and everything was running very smoothly. Now, I have got a requirement to use JSF's [view scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html), so it means I have to create a JSF managed bean (which I did using JSF annotations and all).

Now, I want to access this JSF bean in a Spring bean, certainly I cannot inject or get it using Spring's application context because Spring container doesn't know about this bean. So, currently in my Spring bean code I am getting this JSF bean using JSF's EL Resolver (examples mentioned [here](https://memorynotfound.com/jsf-access-managed-bean-programatically/)).

What I want to know is that is there any better way to do this?

My application is on Spring 4.0 and JSF 2.0 (MyFaces implementation), please let me know if you need any other information. I have not placed code because all my code is in remote server, moreover I think code is not required for this as there is no debugging over here.